# Bing Image Search API autocorrect feature...?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, bing-api

I am trying to use BING's image search api, but the problem is when I miss-spell something it automatically corrects the and doesn't tell me that "Hey we have auto-corrected your query!" , I want to know if my query has been auto corrected and what's the replacement word they have used.. Has anyone done this before...?

This is the query I am using.. note "Aemrica" has been mis-spelled deliberately but it still it gives me results for "America"

https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/Image?Query=%27Aemrica%27&$top=50&$format=JSON

but does not tell anything that the word has been replaced. Is there any way around it..?

i am using the response for iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>No there is no way around this. Even the SearchResponse.Query.SearchTerms response parameter appears to still be the incorrectly spelt version.</s>

I would suggest contacting Microsoft if this is a big issue for you.

EDIT: If you upgrade to the [new Bing Search API based on the Azure marketplace](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/search#schema), you can now get this data by first making a call to the SpellingSuggestions endpoint.

Comment: is there a way to force it search for a particular word..? Like if I search for "xlox" instead of "xbox" it automatically returns results for "xbox" is there anyway I can force it to show results only for "xlox".. ? thanks.